# Problem syncing contacts: HTTP error 500 in logs

Tags: contacts, sync, samsung-galaxy-s-3

I'm trying to find if there's a way to see which HTTP requests are being done on a server. The reason is I'm trying to troubleshoot a problem with contact synchronization.

I've been having a problem synchronizing my GMail contacts on my Android phone (Galaxy SIII). The date for the last sync is well over a month ago and the two arrows that rotate to indicate activity are static and permanently present in the Sync settings screen.

However, contact data does seem to be synchronized between my phone and the GMail server: new contacts created in one appear in the other, and modifications on one side are then synchronized back to the other.

If I press `Cancel sync` I used to get a [toast](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) saying that there are temporary problems and to try later (I think the message was "sync is currently experiencing problems. It will be back shortly"). But now nothing happens when I press `Cancel sync`.

Deleting all the Google contact data in the phone and then re-syncing is not an option for two reasons:

1. If the problem is with a contact in the server then it won't fix the issue
2. I don't want to risk losing data that I added on the phone and wasn't sent to the server yet.

I turned on developer mode to get ADB logs; the following line seemed the most relevant (repeated 8 times):

```
D/ContactsSyncAdapter( 2964): IOException: java.io.IOException: received unhandled http error: 500
```

then followed by

```
D/SyncManager( 2257): failed sync operation , SyncResult: stats [ numIoExceptions: 8]
```

I think that there are 8 contacts that somehow are not able to be synchronized, but I can't really find out which ones. Finding the HTTP requests that end with a 500 error could potentially reveal which contacts might be causing trouble or more troubleshooting clues.

I'd like to avoid rooting my phone, but I do have a full Android SDK and source environment set up. I've tried using DDMS but haven't been able to make it show if/which requests are being sent to the server.

Comment: Give it a while, these sort of things happens from time to time... :)

Comment: HTTP 500 error is "Internal Server Error", so I doubt there's a lot that you can do, since the problem is on Google's end.

Comment: For server-side trouble, there's always the [Google Dashboard Monitor](http://www.google.com/appsstatus) one can check. Currently it shows no server trouble -- though it seems I cannot sync on my phone either (indicators white instead of green for 2 days now).

Comment: @onik I understand that, but if the url is something like googlecontacts.com/get?contact=Mike.Stipe then I can try and delete that contact and re-create it and see if that helps.

Comment: The problem is known and you should star the issue or improve bug reporting so it gets some attention by Google: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42641

Comment: @hurikhan77 Thanks. I've seen it and starred it also, however that report site is for aosp bugs and not for google services.